# Using FMOD in multiple classes (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, singleton, fmod

I am developing an iOS app where I am recording sound from the devices mic, saving it to a wav, then it needs to be accessed and played from a different view controller. As I understand, a FMOD::System object can only be defined in one view controller.

What would be the best way to access FMOD in more than one view controller?

I have tried using a Singleton class, however with objective-c's lack of class (non-instance) variables, I am not sure how declare the FMOD::System variable.

Has anyone successfully implemented what I am trying to do? Any help appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making a singleton class and got it working.

If anyone would like help doing the same just ask.